# How do I change assigned redirect url to drupal root url?

Tags: installation, uri

Sorry I really don't know how to actually ask this.... But let me explain.... 
I have my drupal installed in a subdirectory (www.mydomain.com/my-drupal-install). If I type that in the browser url address bar it works fine - drupal loads and I can navigate all links within the domain and the user and admin configuration loads as well. I have set a domain name to that directory in godaddy shared hosting so if I now type (www.my-drupal-install.com) the first page loads but it will not allow me to navigate to any links not even the user or admin login links. I get a 504 error... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.........
You just have to reset the base url ($base_url = 'http://www.example.com';) in your main settings.php file to whatever your desired url is and refresh the page... It should work fine afterwards.

Thanks anyways.